# How to get and set Textfield value in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, controller, textfield

Sample Data

data

```
data1
data2
data3
    data_detail
    data_detail1
        score - > textfield
```

tabel data, how do i do set or get data on scrore, i use textfield.
is it possible to use controller?

Structure Example

```html
Listview.builder(
    itemCount : anything.length
    itemBuilder:(context, index){

    Listview.Builder(
    itemCount : anything[data][index][data_detail].length
    itemBuilder:(context, index2){
            
        Textfield (
        controller : ??     
        )


        }
    )   
}
)
```

with a structure like that I'm quite confused about the use of controllers in textfields, is it possible to use a list controller with such a structure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `TextEditingController` for this.

First, define a TextEditingController:

```
final TextEditingController txtController = TextEditingController();
```

To `get` the value from a `TextField` use `txtController.text` and to `set` the value use `txtController.text = 'new value'`

Answer (score 0):

because of the position data as in the question, here I use `OnChange`

```dart
Textfield(
onChanged: (text) {
   your_data/varibale.position = text
}
```

thus there is no need to create a list in the controller to retrieve the value from the textfield